# Removed 'Search', now most of header is a clickable area

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I've removed the Search function from the theme 'Corporate' (by WP Explorer), I've deleted Search.php Searchform.php, search from CSS and also Search from the Header file, however the area where search was is now clickable, linking to homepage.

Header info below:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Corporate WPExplorer Theme
 * @since Corporate 1.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <?php if ( get_theme_mod('wpex_custom_favicon') ) { ?>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_theme_mod('wpex_custom_favicon'); ?>" />
    <?php } ?>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <div id="wrap" class="clr container">
        <div id="header-wrap" class="clr">
            <header id="header" class="site-header clr" role="banner">
                <?php
                // Outputs the site logo
                // See functions/logo.php
                wpex_logo(); ?>
            <!-- Search removed from here -->
            </header><!-- #header -->
        </div><!-- #header-wrap -->

        <div id="sidr-close"><a href="#sidr-close" class="toggle-sidr-close"></a></div>
        <div id="site-navigation-wrap">
            <a href="#sidr-main" id="navigation-toggle"><span class="fa fa-bars"></span><?php echo __( 'Menu', 'wpex' ); ?></a>
            <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation clr" role="navigation">
                <?php
                // Display main menu
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location'    => 'main_menu',
                    'sort_column'       => 'menu_order',
                    'menu_class'        => 'dropdown-menu sf-menu',
                    'fallback_cb'       => false
                ) ); ?>
            </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
        </div><!-- #site-navigation-wrap -->

        <div id="main" class="site-main clr">
```

Comment: Cant see any open <a> tags so perhaps you have some js attached to `id="header"`

Comment: here is navigation area... <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation clr" role="navigation">
                <?php
                // Display main menu
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location'    => 'main_menu',
                    'sort_column'       => 'menu_order',
                    'menu_class'        => 'dropdown-menu sf-menu',
                    'fallback_cb'       => false
                ) ); ?>
            </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

Comment: Its normal as in any WordPress theme, calling from function.php like in twentytweleve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the search div back, but only remove the code within the div. By removing the div, you removed the space that it was taking up and the logo's clickable area was extended to be wider. Removing it fully will require some CSS edits.

Comment: @dreamyourcareer Only a pleasure.